# Multiple languages Symfony And JMSI18Routing

Tags: php, symfony, locale, multilingual

I have successfully set up a multi language website with the following code:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
default_locale: %locale%
locales: %locales%
strategy: custom
hosts:
    nl: www.domain.nl
    be: www.domain.be
    en: www.domain.com
redirect_to_host: true
```

But now i want to add a new language but with a different `strategy`

For example `en` is redirecting to `www.domain.com`
The locale i want to add is `it` and it has to use `strategy: prefix` only on the `.com` site.

So when a user goes to `en` it shows `www.domain.com` and `it` shows `www.domain.com/it` but the other languages need to redirect as it is.

I have tried adding a new host with `it: www.domain.com/it` but that results to an 404.

Also, is it possible to add a second `jms_i18n_routing:` with other values for the `it` language ?